# Why doesn't margin:auto center an image?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="queuedError.jpg" style="margin:auto; width:200px;" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `div` expands to 100% as it should but the image does not center itself. Why?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Because your image is an [**inline-block element**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Inline_elements). You could change it to a [**block-level element**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Block_elements) like this:

```
<img src="queuedError.jpg" style="margin:auto; width:200px;display:block" />
```

and it will be centered.

Comment: Sending love all the way from the Ukraine to you in this difficult times in appreciation of your answer. This was the key `display:block`

Answer (score 12):

You need to render it as block level;

```
img {
   display: block;
   width: auto;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why does it only align horizontally and not vertically?

Comment: Vertical alignment is not as straight forward as you might have hoped. It's all down to the CSS spec - check out this beautifully concise article on the matter - http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 8):

Add `style="text-align:center;"`

try below code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
        <img src="queuedError.jpg" style="margin:auto; width:200px;" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think your answer is incorrect but yours is lacking any explanation of the display type.

Comment: Although your answer can be considered as an alternate solution, I would not advise it. The reason being the fact that if you add anything else inside the div, a heading, for example, it would align center with the image. To align the heading to the left, you would have to write more styles for it. You will have to keep doing this for whatever you add into the div. So adding `display: block;` to the image is highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

i know this is an old post, but wanted to share how i solved the same problem.

My image was inheriting a float:left from a parent class. By setting float:none I was able to make margin:0 auto and display: block work properly. Hope it may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <img src="queuedError.jpg" style="margin:auto; width:200px;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I must define a specific width for the object or nothing else will make it center. A relative width doesn't work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: My point was, while several people have given answers that work, they only work if the code includes a specific definition of the object's width. Ex: <img [...etc., etc.,...] style="display:block; margin:auto; width:200px" /> will work, but don't use a relative size, like "width:50%".

Of course, if you use "width:100%" then centering is not an issue, because there is then no margin on the left or right of the object.

Answer (score 0):

open `div` then put

```
style="width:100% ; margin:0px auto;"
```

`image` tag (or) content

close div

Answer (score -1):

I have found...
margin: 0 auto; works for me. But I have also seen it NOT work due to the class being trumped by another specificity that had ... float:left;
so watch for that you may need to add ... float:none; this worked in my case as I was coding a media query.