# Centering image gallery with jQuery, math calculation

Tags: jquery, css

Well, it's a bit confusing, but you can see here: http://www.stevenacres.com/meggriffiths/#bettydew

The images need to be centered. The captions also need to be flush left with the image, and the nav flush right. I couldn't use `display:table-cell` because I'm already using `display:none` to get the gallery to function properly, and since I have to use `position:absolute` and `top:0` to get them to overlay, I can't really center them.

So I have the following two lines of jQuery:

```
$('.gallery ul li').each(function() {
    $('.gallery ul li').width($('.gallery ul li > img').width());
    $('.gallery ul li').css('margin-left','$(".gallery ul li > img").width() / 2');
});
```

The first one gets the width of each image and sets the `li` accordingly... that way, the caption and such can sit wherever the image sits. The second line is supposed to find the image's width, and set the css margin-left to the **negative** of this value, but I can't get the math calculation to work. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code that ended up working:

```
$('.gallery ul li').each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).children().children().width() + 26);
    $(this).css('margin-left',-$(this).children().children().width() / 2 - 13);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is in this line of code....

```
$('.gallery ul li').css('margin-left','$(".gallery ul li > img").width() / 2')
```

width() returns value in pixels and you are doing arithmetic operation on it..so it will better if you parse it first and then do that calculation..

```
$('.gallery ul li').css('margin-left','parseInt($(".gallery ul li > img").width()) / 2')
```

i think this might be helpful to you...

Comment: That didn't really seem to do it. Is there a way to make this value negative, as it needs to pull the images to the left.

Comment: yes!! you can subtract pixels from width..but you have to calculate how much pixels will be required in order to place it in exact position.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be running the code in the correct spot.  You are loading the gallery dynamically with jQuery's `load`. So the code should be inside the `load`'s callback.

Furthermore, since your images might not be loaded at the time this code executes, you might not have the correct `width()` for the images, and your code probably won't work.  You should really try to find a solution with css.  Maybe with [margin auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015223/why-doesnt-marginauto-center-an-image)? Otherwise your code will have to be pretty complex to handle many of the edge cases.

Comment: I think you are right. I tried margin auto on everything, but since the images have to be `position:absolute` the margin auto doesn't work...

Comment: Why do they have to be `position:absolute`?  When I open the developer tools window in chorme, and turn off `position:absolute` for `.gallery ul li` on your site.  The images center perfectly.

Comment: Make sure to add a `<div style="clear:both;"/>` to your code to make sure your `float` divs are cleared.

Comment: If the gallery is up on #bettydew and you click the image to go to the next, without `position:absolute` the image appears under until the other fades out, then pops back on to the top. And I'm not sure what you mean by adding the clear style... what specific element are you talking about? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I just checked with Chrome dev tools and yes it looks like it centers it correctly, which it does, but it also shows it fading from one to the other properly. If you look now, you can see what it does. The image won't load behind the first one, it loads below it and then pops into position once the other one has faded out.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out by just using `margin auto`, but I figured it out with the method I was working on before. I added it in up in the original post.