# HTML/CSS : margin:auto not working for <img> tag

Tags: html, css

I made an html document and I put an `<img>` tag in it.
I want to align center the image using `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` 
but it not working. Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img {
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

what is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't margin:auto center an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015223/why-doesnt-marginauto-center-an-image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your `<img>` to a block element. Add `display: block;` to your CSS and it will center.

```
img{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display: block;
}
```

`<img>` tags by default are inline-block, which doesn't center when using the margin trick.

Also, instead of having both `margin-left` and `margin-right` you can just use `margin` You don't have to, but I always like having as few lines of code as possible.

```
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like that with CSS, but HTML also has a build-in option for that.
Good luck!

```
<html><body><img src="IMG SRC HERE" align="center/right"></html></body>
```