# Center element in a div explaining

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen a lot posts about this, I know it's simple but I cannot get my example to work and I would like to understand why as I still did not grasp the concept of positioning in CSS.

I am using simple bootstrap in my App. I have a `container` with `row` and `col-md-6`. My code looks like this.

```
<section id="automat" class="box bg-light-grey">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <img src="images/iPod.png" class="scaleImage"/>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

And my custom css style for image looks like this (depending on screen size I will control the size of img element).

```
.scaleImage {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

As you can see, I have tried to set the exact `width` of my element, with `position:relative` and `margin:0 auto`. According to the other posts, this is supposed to be enough to center my element inside my container, but it's not. It is still locked on the very left side of my `col-md-6` container.

My question is following: Why my solution is not working and how do I need to change my code to get this to work?

Comment: try to use text-center, text-left and text-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this working?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
         <img src="images/iPod.png" class="scaleImage" style="width:100%;height:100%"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is thank you! but why? I can see that it's `text-align:center` but the element we are targeting is an `img` ? This sounds illogical to me

Comment: You can even remove the `text-align:center`. See this two examples I have made: http://www.bootply.com/RlUZslmj1P    and     http://www.bootply.com/PrJ0GJsB2S. The problem is that the columns do not sum up to 12.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```css
section{
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="automat" class="box bg-light-grey">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <img src="https://www.sfu.ca/content/sfu/publicsquare/_jcr_content/below-nav/parsys/image.img.jpg/1406566003083.jpg" class="scaleImage" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap class 'text-center' to center. So, you do not need to use margin:0 auto.

Here you have defined an offset too. You do not need offset to center a div.

```css
.scaleImage {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="automat" class="box bg-light-grey">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                    <img src="https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/tcbxa1Eb6YMETIW2.large" class="scaleImage"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto` would not work because image is inline-block element (look: [Why doesn't margin:auto center an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015223/why-doesnt-marginauto-center-an-image)) 
To align image do `text-align: center` on parent div or `<div class="container text-center">`.

Answer (score 0):

try to add one more class, text-center to col-md-6. It will center align the content.

```
position:relative;
float:none;
width:100%;
max-width:300px;
margin:auto;
DISPLAY:BLOCK
```

so to center your element in the middle you need this combination of css properties